# Determinated threads running with X cores?

Tags: multithreading, cpu-cores

If I have 8 asynchronous functions to execute and 4 cores in my CPU, What is better (more speedy and correct)?

1. Start 4 threads and when finish a thread, start another thread, etc.
2. Start 8 threads

Language aren't important.

Comment: 3. Put the 8 tasks into a queue, start 4 threads, and each thread takes tasks from the queue until the queue is empty.

Comment: 1 = 3.
I wanted to say this.

Comment: @nosid As chmee's answer notes, if I/O latency is a factor, then providing extra threads for the OS to schedule can allow work to be done while one thread waits for I/O. With a work queue and four threads, if one thread waits for I/O that thread's core is unused. (This assumes that asynchronous I/O is not used.)

Comment: I revoted, sorry. Great answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: It depends.

It depends on the workload.  If threads are I/O bound, you can benefit by starting all 8 threads.  If they're highly CPU bound, then it makes less sense.

Comment: @user3602030 If threads are I/O (latency) bound, they will tend to stall waiting for I/O to complete. If extra threads are available, the OS can schedule them while any stalled threads wait for I/O.